# Splitting value_counts() into axis

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

```
myData = df['Year'].value_counts().sort_index()
```

I'm running the above to tally the occurrences of each year in my dataset. Returning back data as such:

```
1600     4
1601     2
1602     1
1603     1
1604     5
    ..
2016    52
2017    64
2018    65
2019    61
2020    20
```

The left hand column is the year and the right hand side is it's tally. I need to graph the data so I need to sort these into an x and y axis. But I don't know how?

Any help? Thanks.

Comment: do you need `myData.plot()` ?

Comment: Was using matplotlib?

Comment: yop, under the hood.